# Build sitemap using c#

Tags: c#

Does anyone know a way to build a sitemap of a website using c#.

I want to be able to point to a website and generate a full sitemap.

Any ideas on how best to approach this?

Sp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write an app to do it, you want to write what's known as a "Web Crawler".  Google it and you'll come up with tons of articles and code samples on it.

Here's one:  http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84330/building-a-web-crawler/

If you want a simpler solution, you can try this: http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

Comment: This is just what I was after. Many Thanks Steve

Answer (score -1):

Well there is a recipe for that here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab.aspx

Comment: I need to be able to do it for sites that I don't own.

Comment: No, that doesn't do what the OP wants. This is for creating a sitemap to *your own* website in ASP.NET, but the OP seems to want some kind of crawler that generates a site map.

Comment: sorry, was a little fast there